# Image doesn't save in public folder laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning laravel but I have problem now with the image,
I want it to save it in storage/app/public/avatar so I can show it, but it keep saving it in storage/app/avatar

I write this in the .env

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

And then I generate the storage link

```
php artisan storage:link
```

but still the same, every time I upload a photo it saving it in storage/app/avatar

Anyone can help me?

In filesystems.php

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Here :

```
 $attributes['avatar'] = request('avatar')->store('public/avatars');
```

In USer.php

```
public function getAvatarAttribute($value)
{
    return asset($value);
}
```

this method was working correctly when i was using a random avatar link,
but now it show nothing, i check my database and the link is there and it's right

```
public function getAvatarAttribute($value)
 {
    asset('storage/avatars/'.$image->name);
 }

$attributes['avatar'] = request('avatar')->store('public/avatars');
```

In the controller, update method:

```
    $user->update($attributes);
    $user->password = Hash::make($user['password']);
    $user->save();
    return redirect($user->path());
```

In the show.blade

```
 <img
            src= "{{ $user->avatar }}"
            alt=""
            class="rounded-full mr-4 absolute"
            style="width: 150px; left: calc(50% - 75px); top: 300px"
        >
```

but the src become "(unknown)"

Comment: Hi Ali can you please show your code where you are trying to save the image?

Comment: You think i should write store('public/avatars') ?

Comment: yeah! possibly making use of `$image->move($filepath,$filename);`

Comment: Okay i update it to     store('public/avatars'), and it's work, but now  i didn't display the image on the web site, i will update the code

Comment: you also need to save the url to the image. or with `assert('/avatars/filename.file-ext')`

Comment: How to change the store() method path so save?
i tried move() and it's works, but it link the image didn't make a copy in public

Answer (score 1):

Change "FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public" to

```
FILESYSTEM_DISK=public
```

Or remove that line completely and directly set public folder as default disk in filesystems.php as follows:

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'public'),
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a configuration cache issue as your filesystem looks properly configured.

The `storage/app` folder is the path of laravel's default disk (the `local` disk). Since you had specified to use public as the default disk in .env but your application is still using the local disk path, it looks like a cache issue

Try using

```
php artisan config:clear
```

And then attempt

```
request('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

If it was indeed a cache issue, then the file should be stored in the `storage/app/public` folder.

To get the full path to the image, use

```
Storage::url('avatar/'.$user->avatar);
```

So in the accessor, use

```
public function getAvatarAttribute($value)
{
    return Storage::url('avatar/'.$value);
}
```

Using `asset()` to get the path to the file is not recommended because if some day you wish to switch storage to the cloud (S3, or any other storage. basically, you want to not use the storage folder of your application), then the `asset()` will no longer give you the correct path and you'd need to change it everywhere. But when using the storage facade, all you need to do is change it in the filesystems.php

Also, just to test it yourself, you could also specify the disk when storing by specifying the disk as the second argument to the store method

```
request('avatar')->store('avatars', 'public');
Storage::disk('public')->url('avatar/'.$user->avatar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget to delete `public/storage` folder

and then re-run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

This is important

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is still looking for the answer. Solved it by as follows:

```
 $attributes['avatar'] = request('avatar')->store('/avatars', public);
```

Answer (score -1):

The store method stores the files in **storage/app** directory. That's why your code is storing the image in storage/app/**avatars**

```
request('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

This will place it under storage/app/public/avatars

```
 request('avatar')->store('public/avatars');
```

To show it

```
asset('storage/avatars/`.$image->name)
```

Comment: It works but it didn't read the image, i will update the codes